# How to connect CSS files with gorilla mux

Tags: css, go, gorilla

I have this directory structure and I'm using gorilla mux:

[image]

I trying to connect CSS-files like this:

```
func main() {

    r := mux.NewRouter()

    fileServer := http.FileServer(http.Dir("../static"))
    r.PathPrefix("/static/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/static/", fileServer))

    r.HandleFunc("/", controllers.Home)
    r.HandleFunc("/product", controllers.Home)
    r.HandleFunc("/product/index", controllers.Home)

    r.HandleFunc("/cart", controllers.Index)
    r.HandleFunc("/cart/index", controllers.Index)
    r.HandleFunc("/cart/buy", controllers.Buy)
    r.HandleFunc("/cart/remove", controllers.Remove)

    r.HandleFunc("/api/user/new", app.CreateAccount)
    app.Init()
    r.HandleFunc("/api/user/login", app.Authenticate)

    r.Use(app.JWTAuthentication)

    err := http.ListenAndServe(":8000", r)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

**html**

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/content.css" >
```

**connect html file**

```
ts, err := template.ParseFiles("../static/html/index.html")
```

When i open localhost i see only html file, without css.

If i use standard http router, then this works correctly.

Comment: You can use `tree` to show your folder structure properly. Its hard to interpret like this.

Comment: Also maybe describe what your problem is, I cannot tell from your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Serve static html files with gorilla mux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50651523/serve-static-html-files-with-gorilla-mux)

Comment: You probably want to move the css directory under static.  Edit the question to show the html  pages reference the css file (specifically, show the path to the css file).

Comment: @TheFool when i open localhost i see only html file, without css